# Invalid read of size 4 while using fgets from a file

Tags: c

I'm having trouble figuring out why my code is having a seg fault while reading code from a file in c. I've attached the code and valgrind output below. Thanks for any help!

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("filename", "r");
char line[100];
while (fgets(line, 100, fp) != NULL) {
```

```
==4545== Invalid read of size 4
==4545==    at 0x4E9E34B: fgets (iofgets.c:50)
==4545==    by 0x401289: main (game.c:180)
==4545==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==4545==
==4545==
==4545== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==4545==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==4545==    at 0x4E9E34B: fgets (iofgets.c:50)
==4545==    by 0x401289: main (game.c:180)
```

Comment: You did not check if `fp` is `NULL`.

Comment: @alinsoar: found a better one, a duplicate should have the problem of not checking a pointer returned by a library call...

Answer (score 4):

This line

```
==4545==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

tells you you're dereferencing a `NULL` pointer (Address `0x0` ...)!

With the code you show, this can only mean `fopen` failed and returned `0`/`NULL`. Always check the return values of your function calls.

Comment: [The Ten Commandments for C Programmers](http://skull.piratehaven.org/~bapper/298c/ten-commandments.html), items 2 and 6. ;-)

Comment: haha, nice document :)

Comment: It's positively ancient (I've seen this in the 80's...), but most items are still surprisingly topical. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar well, I don't necessarily agree with item 3 there. Often good, but imagine you're dealing with pointer types: either the cast is unnecessary (and all is fine) or you're accessing an object through a wrong type (UB) and a cast would just silence the compiler about it...

Comment: Items 4 and 9 are artifacts of a bygone era as well, but an interesting glimpse of the past. The rest is pure gold to this day. ;-)

Comment: So does that mean that the file I'm trying to open doesn't exist?

Comment: @DuKangaroo no, it means opening it fails. The file not existing is **one** possible reason, others include wrong permissions etc.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've managed to get that part working now.